# div's inside parent div side by side with percent widths

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating facebook home page replica with divs in percentage like first, third and fourth column of 20% of screen width and second column of 40%. 
Earlier I was using bootstraps grid system layout then it was working but it was difficult to manage columns widths in given percentages so I changed it into simple divs with respected percentages but now all divs are one under another rather than side by side.

[Here](http://chu.pe/5mB)

is the jsfiddle link.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The issue is that each of the columns will default to `display: block;` which will cause subsuquent `div`'s to _flow_ beneath them and not side-by-side. A relatively easy way to fix this is to simply set the `.main-container` to a `display: flex;` [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Here is a working example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7gy8vom4/2/). Change is on line `282` of the CSS.

Comment: @varbrad, thanks it was a silly mistake. Really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using flexbox. For your case, apply the following rules to the parent container:

```
display: flex;
align-items: stretch;
```

That will ensure that the divs line up side-by-side and that they will all be the same height. To ensure that columns 1, 3, & 4 are all the same width apply `flex: 1` to each of them. To make column 2 twice the width of the other columns apply `flex: 2`.

Updated jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/b0rds1ch/

If you want to learn more about flexbox (it's very helpful for layout) there is a [great write-up](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on CSS-Tricks.

Comment: Flexbox is super helpful for layout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put float:left; in your .col then they would be side by side.

hope this helps.